# Angular 1.5 Component - dependency injection

Tags: angularjs, components

My goal was to use dependency injection of a constant value (the base URL) to use in defining the component's templateUrl property.  Nothing so far has worked. The code below is in Typescript

Some explanation:  app.core.Iconstants holds the baseUrl value.
                   app.core.AngularGlobals.appCoreConstants is the string representing "app.core.Constants".

Mind you, I'm just cutting my teeth of Angular.

namespace donationEntry.Components{
    "use strict";

```
class test1 implements ng.IComponentOptions {
    public static id: string = AngularGlobals.donationEntry + ".test1";
    bindings: any;
    controller: any;
    templateUrl: string;

    constructor(clientContext: app.core.IConstants) {
        this.bindings = {
            textBinding: '@',
            dataBinding: '<',
            functionBinding: '&'
        };
        this.controller = TestController;
        this.templateUrl = clientContext.baseUrl + "Areas/ng/app/fundraising/donationEntry/components/test1/test1.html";
    }
}

// register the controller with app
angular.module(AngularGlobals.donationEntry)
    .component("test1", [app.core.AngularGlobals.appCoreConstants, (c) => new test1(c)]);
```

}

When I run this, I end up with the following error:

angular.js:61 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module donationEntry due to:
TypeError: t.charAt is not a function

Comment: Says you are calling charAt on an object that doesn't have charAt, but I don't see charAt anywhere in the snippet you provided, are you sure this is where the problem is?

Comment: Having circumvented the problem, I never dug deeper, however it seems related to the shortcut injection syntax I used.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work, though I wouldn't call it the most eloquent of answers.  Again, written in Typescript:

namespace donationEntry.Components{
    "use strict";

```
class test1 implements ng.IComponentOptions {
    public static id: string = AngularGlobals.donationEntry + ".test1";
    bindings: any;
    controller: any;
    templateUrl: string;


    constructor(clientContext: app.core.IConstants) {
        this.bindings = {
            textBinding: '@',
            dataBinding: '<',
            functionBinding: '&'
        };
        this.controller = TestController;
        this.templateUrl = clientContext.baseUrl + "Areas/ng/app/fundraising/donationEntry/components/test1/test1.html";
    }
}

// register the controller with app
var clientContext = <app.core.IConstants>angular.injector(['ng', app.core.AngularGlobals.appCore]).get(app.core.AngularGlobals.appCoreConstants);
angular.module(AngularGlobals.donationEntry)
    .component("test1", new test1(clientContext));
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I try to stay away from Angular's injection or module mechanism whenever I can, preferring straight ES6.

You can do:

```
//clientContext.ts
export = { baseUrl: 'whateva' }
```

And then import like this:

```
import clientContext from './path/to/clientContext'
```

Comment: Thanks. That would be great, however even the client context path itself would be subject to needing a dynamic base literal (our clients would have a different one than us). Certainly understand your dislike for injection, heh.